# PCB soldermask endurance

Tags: pcb

I have a PCB where there is mounted a microphone, on page 17 in the [datasheet](https://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/INMP521.pdf), there is a PCB landpattern with broken GND ring.

I have used this landpattern and routed traces through the opening.

But the microphone has an pad there, so directly above the traces there is soldermask and then the pad.

I was thinking if this could be a problem, that the PAD might short with the traces, or should the soldermask be able to keep the isolation ?

Below is a picture of my routing, the grid is 0.1mm.

[image: microphone routing]

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. But I would place some GND via on the lower part of the ring as well.

Comment: I agree with Botnic. You can use a bit of silkscreen over the track as extra protection if you are worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the linked datasheet:

> Note that in both of these patterns, the solid ring around the sound
>   port is still present; this ring is needed to ground the microphone
>   and for acoustic performance. The pad on the package connected to this
>   ring is ground and still needs a solid electrical connection to the
>   PCB ground. If a land pattern similar to Figure 16 or Figure 17 is
>   used on a PCB, make sure that the unconnected rectangle on the bottom
>   of the INMP521 is not placed directly over any exposed copper. The
>   ring on the microphone is still at ground, and any PCB traces routed
>   beneath it must be properly masked to avoid short circuits.

As it says, avoid **exposed** copper. Standard solder mask should be sufficient to insulate traces from the ground ring on the device. If in doubt, you can use vias and put the traces on another layer.